# Customized checkbox for TableView gives NSManagedObject error

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmanagedobject

I tried to set up a customized Accessory Checkbox for my TableView and got stuck with this error...

> Expected method to read dictionary element not found on element of type NSManagedObject

Code of my ViewController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *device = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        device = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        device = [self.cart objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    }

    if (cell.accessoryView == nil) 
    {
        // Only configure the Checkbox control once.
        cell.accessoryView = [[Checkbox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 43)];
        cell.accessoryView.opaque = NO;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [(Checkbox*)cell.accessoryView addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxTapped:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"cartProductName"]]];

        [(Checkbox*)cell.accessoryView setChecked: [device[@"checked"] boolValue] ];//<-- Errorline            

        // Accessibility

        [self updatetAccessibilityForCell:cell];

        return cell;
    }
```

The error happens on the `setChecked:` line.

My CoreData is:

Cart.h:

```
@interface Cart : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * cartProductName;

@end
```

Cart.m:

```
@implementation Cart

@dynamic cartProductName;

@end
```

Do i Need a new property for completed?

Head of my ViewController:

```
#import "CartViewController.h"
#import "Checkbox.h"
#import "Cart.h"


@interface CartViewController ()
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *cart;

@end

@implementation CartViewController {
    NSArray *cartProducts;
    NSArray *searchResults;}
@synthesize searchbar;
```

Sorry, I'm pretty new in the programming world...

Answer (score 0):

Change `[device[@"checked"] boolValue]` to `[device.checked boolValue]`

You're not accessing an `NSDictionary` but an `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: thanks for your help, but this does not work either :-/ Error: Property 'checked' not found on object of type 'NSManagedObject *'

Comment: Sorry, you have to cast to the actual type of device. I.e. `[((Device *)device).checked boolValue]`

Comment: I tried to include this feature: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Accessory/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: when i copy [((Device *)device).checked boolValue] into the code the offers me to replace 'Device' with 'device, but then the compiler expects a expression... :-/

Comment: Do you know which Expressesion is needed?

Comment: You need to use the actual class of your `device`. Should be the same as in your Core Data database.